# not able to copy the blob in GOOGLE CLOUD from one bucket to another bucket please find code below

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to copy the file from one Google Cloud Storage bucket to another in GCP, the function is getting deployed successfully but its not working.

Please see the below sample code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
def copy(
    bucket_name, blob_name, destination_bucket_name, destination_blob_name
):
    """Copies a blob from one bucket to another with a new name."""
    bucket_name = "ups_vikky_test56"
    blob_name = "city.csv"
    destination_bucket_name = "ups_vikky_test57"
    destination_blob_name = "city.csv" + "temp"


    storage_client = storage.Client()

    source_bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    source_blob = source_bucket.blob(blob_name)
    destination_bucket = storage_client.bucket(destination_bucket_name)

    blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(
        source_blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob_name
    )

    print(
        "Blob {} in bucket {} copied to blob {} in bucket {}.".format(
            source_blob.name,
            source_bucket.name,
            blob_copy.name,
            destination_bucket.name,
        )
    )
```

Comment: Please, format your question properly at first.

Comment: hi i am not able to copy the file in google storage from one bucket to another bucket , please find the sample code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the code and it works properly. First, before deploying your code, make sure that your Cloud Function's entry point is correct. It must be the name of the function in your source code to be executed, which in this case is `copy`.

And last, if you're deploying with an HTTP trigger, you must always pass an argument and it needs to be included even if you're not using it. If you're using background functions, there must be 2 arguments. See the overview and examples in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#types_of_cloud_functions).

Here's a sample of a function with HTTP trigger:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
def copy(request):
    """Copies a blob from one bucket to another with a new name."""
    bucket_name = "ups_vikky_test56"
    blob_name = "city.csv"
    destination_bucket_name = "ups_vikky_test57"
    destination_blob_name = "city.csv" + "temp"

    # ... the rest of your logic
```